# Broken packages because of trying to install Adobe ConnectAddIn

Tags: package-management, removing

On 13.04 I tried to install Adobe ConnectAddIn, but now I have broken packages all because of it. I have tried `sudo apt-get install -f`, and removed the .deb file, but still I have 4 broken packages, ConnectAddIn, and the 3 libmtrf0 files.

Is there anyway to remove these broken packages? Synaptic doesn't seem to want to remove these.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

if that doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get purge  ConnectAddIn
sudo apt-get autoremove
```